# Permalink refresh, the good, the bad, etc. What is best?

Tags: permalinks, tags

I have written various functions/plugins and they require Permalinks to be refreshed, or switched form settings plain then back to to post name in Permalinks settings; to make urls of custom post types function with the newly added /url/ in the address that are from new categories or tags, etc. I found a few automatic methods of this Permalinks refresh shown below. Some people write that doing this refresh slows down the website.?? Is it true it slows the website?

option #1 :

```
add_action('wp_insert_category', function () { flush_rewrite_rules(true); }, 10, 2);
```

option #2 :

```
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

I don't think I got the first one to work but the second one surely works good. #2 works good. But is there a better option? A way to do this to not slow down the website?

Thanks! Have a great day!!

**Edit: regardless it's not logical to be needing to visit the permalink page every time new cats or tags are used, edited, added. it would not be a normal memory process to do so and people will forget. Please tell me better way to refresh the Permalinks automatically?**

Comment: that function is expensive and does a lot of work, you should only call it when it needs to be called. If it wasn't expensive then it wouldn't exist and rewrite rules would be generated on each page load ( longterm plans to optimise the function further are with the goal of automating it ). I would not recommend those options, it should be enough to visit the permalinks page without saving to flush rewrite rules

Comment: that's what i wrote in my post. i already know this. but still need to solve the problem. for example some users might not have access to the settings. so the wp needs to do this all automatically.

Comment: Need to find a better option. A way to do this to not slow down the website?

Comment: Just visiting the permalink settings page is enough, but if a user can't access the settings then they wouldn't be able to activate your theme/plugin, so it wouldn't matter? Or is there something you're not telling us? Your first example implies that you're doing something when a category is inserted that requires rewrite rules to be flushed, which implies that you've made a massive mistake that you've not realised, one that can be fixed by constantly flushing permalinks, and are asking how to automate your solution rather than how to fix the problem. Can you provide more context?

Comment: regardless it's not logical to be needing to visit the permalink page every time new cats or tags are used, edited, added. it would not be a normal memory process to do so and people will forget. have a nice day.

Comment: More information needs to be give as to why and when this needs to happen. But from the information given I agree with @tom, you need to find and fix the issue and not try and patch over it.

Comment: _You should not need to flush permalinks when new categories or tags are created_, it is not normal, something terribly wrong is happening, flushing rewrite rules is not the solution. Normal WP installs do not require this, if yours does then you need to figure out why. What are you doing with categories and tags that requires this? Permalinks/Rewrite rules have generic rules that work for all tags and categories, they do not get updated when new categories are added so they don't need to be flushed. There is no big list of category/tag permalinks that needs flushing and re-saving

Comment: Instead, share your custom functions that require this so that they can be fixed. Needing to flush permalinks when content is created is a sign that something has gone terribly wrong, you should not ignore it